# "Invalid Response from Facebook" when Authenticating with Facebook using Flask-Oauthlib

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, flask, facebook-oauth

I'm consistently getting an "Invalid response from Facebook" error when authenticating over Facebook with Oauthlib when building off of the sample code [here](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/facebook.py).

I've outlined the sections of relevant code below.

**Setup:**

Setting up the Oauth request object.

Not pictured: Navigational routes and Flask app initialization.

```
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth, OAuthException

oauth = OAuth()

facebook = oauth.remote_app('facebook',
  base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/',
  request_token_url=None,
  access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
  authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth',
  consumer_key=config.get("app_id"),
  consumer_secret=config.get("app_secret"),
  request_token_params={'scope': 'public_profile,email'}
)

@facebook.tokengetter
def get_facebook_token():
  if current_user.is_authenticated():
    return current_user.get_facebook_token()

  else:
    return None
```

**Login handler:**

Sending users here in order to begin the process, with the url for the facebook callback appended to the root URL.

```
@app.route('/facebook/login')
def facebook_login():
  return facebook.authorize(callback="http://example.com%s" % url_for('facebook_callback'))
```

**Facebook callback, source of the issue:**

From here I can garner that a code (presumably the token) is returned but Oauthlib fails to parse it correctly.

```
@app.route('/facebook/callback')
def facebook_callback(response):
  response = facebook.authorized_response()
  if response is None:
    flash("You denied the request to sign in.", "error")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

  if isinstance(response, OAuthException):    
    flash("Access denied: %s" % response.message, "error")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

  # Request fails here, returns the redirect above.
```

From dumping the request args I can see fairly clearly that after being directed to Facebook and successfully connecting, there is a very long token being returned to the callback along the lines of '?code=1234567890-abcdefghijklmnop', however actually trying to authenticate with this fails with "Invalid response from Facebook".

Here is a sample request dump:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('code', 'AQAPedwWavTb_cBx6NVy-qy3AL5YPr780oG5tA1LfITpVwkk-kr_4I0lG6B-vlhcYEubhuKhEM46bPs-1WpWUpJzcWfhkQ64lIkdLm9uSHSqeBHBM_6zw7SDpvVmGK-JKWBpAqRJuBKenl9zslQizthox96104iiul0uYQY67cmZgPXZi9uL-mcgZ5dRj387eKJIjNninBXxwCGgFkg5kLVHYt7t0ktUH58stYlxn2f98AXuSlrIvWsA5NeHsVbM8XY0XQrDrNbCvjDmEwHQGkZ3uZRbyaecN7MAi0bM0TrZzpuQ8j3M34DnQp_v9n4ktM4')])
```

Having used similar code based off of the Twitter sample that works, I'm thinking this could be a possible library bug due to Facebook API changes, but I would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this from Google in the future, I solved this in a solution that can be read [here](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/issues/158#issuecomment-92213524).

> Hey there, I solved this issue in a very hacky way which I would not
>   recommend for production environments, but I eventually found the
>   issue a few days after my last message.
>
> When you ask Facebook for an access token, it does NOT give you an
>   access token in the way you might expect. What I assumed to be a
>   failure on Facebook's side was instead a (perhaps intentional)
>   formatting error.
>
> What you might expect:
>
> `http://example.com/callback?access_token=00000000000`
>
> or
>
> `http://example.com/callback`  with the access token passed as a POST
>   argument in the headers.
>
> What *actually* happens is that Facebook responds like this:
>
> `http://example.com/callback?#access_token=0000000000`
>
> Because of this, it is -**impossible**- for any server side language
>   to parse it, as the access token will now only be visible to the
>   browser itself. It is not passed to the backend whatsoever.

Capturing the request:

```
@app.route('/facebook/translate', methods=['GET'])
def facebook_translate():
  # Facebook responds with the access token as ?#access_token, 
  # rather than ?access_token, which is only accessible to the browser.
  # This part is where things get really, really dumb.
  return '''  <script type="text/javascript">
    var token = window.location.href.split("access_token=")[1]; 
    window.location = "/facebook/callback?access_token=" + token;
  </script> '''
```

Proceeding as usual:

```
@app.route('/facebook/callback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def facebook_callback():
  access_token = request.args.get("access_token")

  if access_token == "undefined":
    flash("You denied the request to sign in.", "error")
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

  graph = facebooksdk.GraphAPI(access_token)
  profile = graph.get_object("me")
```